# Negating logical statement of continuity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help negating the following statement please, or if anyone could help putting it into words:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 (\exists d>0(\forall x_0 (\forall x(|x - x_0| < d \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon))))$$

Comment: I've edited your question to include MathJax - please verify that it's correct. Also note that this is one way to define [uniform continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity).

Comment: Do you know how to negate this one? $\forall_\epsilon\left(\exists_\delta \left( \vert x-x_0\vert <\delta \implies \vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert\right)\right)$

Comment: I think it would be: there exists a for epsilon such that(for all values of d(negation of all that's inside))

Answer (score 1):

The negation in words is: there exists a positive $\epsilon$ such that for all positive $\delta$ there exist $x_0$ and $x$ such that the distance between $x$ and $x_0$ is less than $\delta$, but the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ is at least $\epsilon$.

Symbolically, just push negation inside quantifiers by rewriting $\lnot\exists$ as $\forall\lnot$ and $\lnot\forall$ as $\exists\lnot$ and then use de Morgan's laws for the propositional connectives to rewrite, e.g., $\lnot(A \implies B)$ as $A \land \lnot B$.